# how to have indexed files in storage in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, out-of-memory

I have a huge dataset of images and I am processing them one by one.
All the images are stored in a folder.

**My Approach:**

What I have tried is that I have tried reading all the filenames in memory and whenever a call for a certain index is sent, I load the corresponding image.

The problem is that it is even not possible to keep the paths and the names of the files in memory due to the huge dataset.

Is it possible to have an indexed file on storage and one is able to read a file name at a certain index.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're saying that the paths and file names *alone* don't fit into memory (without even opening any files)? How many files is that roughly?

Comment: Roughly 80 million. But the problem is that I have other things loaded in the memory and cant have much for loading the filenames

Comment: Try `os.scandir()` or `glob.iglob()`, these returns an iterator, so you can process files one by one rather than generating a full list of files

Comment: Of course an iterator is not indexible and does not have random access, but that's a tradeoff you gonna have to agree to if you want to avoid putting everything in memory

Comment: I have thought of it but indexing is very important. Would be great if there is something that exists with indexing.

Comment: you'll need a proper database then

Comment: What about using HDF5 (pandas' hdfstore / pytables) to store the filenames?